# Adding description when branchen in Perforce using P4python

Tags: python, perforce, p4python

I already figured out how to branch and submit my changes however since I use a project management platform like Jira I also need to write a description on each check ins.
This is my code for branching :

```
result = p4.run("populate", Path+"/...@"+ Changelist, destination)
```

Where do I write the description? Right now the description is the command itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
C:\Perforce\test\python>p4 help populate

    populate -- Branch a set of files as a one-step operation

    p4 populate [options] fromFile[rev] toFile
    p4 populate [options] -b branch [-r] [toFile[rev]]
    p4 populate [options] -b branch -s fromFile[rev] [toFile]
    p4 populate [options] -S stream [-P parent] [-r] [toFile[rev]]

        options: -d description -f -m max -n -o
```

so:

```
   result = p4.run(
       "populate", 
       "-d",
       "My awesome description",
       f"{src_path}/...@{changelist}", 
       f"{dst_path}/..."
    )
```

You can also use the `integrate` and `submit` commands (note that this requires that `dst_path` is part of your client view since the files will be opened on your client prior to submit):

```
p4.run("integrate", f"{src_path}/...@{changelist}", f"{dst_path}/...")
p4.run("submit", "-d", "My awesome description")
```